# Не запускается php скрипт, указанный в action, при отправке формы

Tags: javascript, html, события

Есть форма регистрации, при нажатии на кнопку регистрации js скрипт проверяет поля на корректность ввода, после выполнения js не запускается php скрипт, указанный в action

вот html:

```
<form action="include/signup.php" class="RegistrationForm" id="regForm" method="post">
                  <section class="inputSection">
                    <section class="registrationForm-section">
                        <section class="firstName-RegSection">
                            <p class="firstName-Reg">
                                Имя:
                            </p>
                            <input data-checkname="true" type="text" class="firstName-RegInput" name="firstName">
                        </section>
                        <section class="lastName-RegSection">
                            <p class="lastName-Reg">
                                Фамилия:
                            </p>
                            <input data-checkname="true" type="text" class="lastName-RegInput" name="lastName">
                        </section>
                        <section class="e-mail-RegSection">
                            <p class="e-mail-Reg">
                              E-mail:
                            </p>
                            <input data-emailcheck="true" type="text" class="e-mail-RegInput" name="e-mail">
                        </section>
                        <section class="phoneNumber-RegSection">
                            <p class="phoneNumber-Reg">
                                Номер телефона:
                            </p>
                            <input data-length="11" type="text" class="phoneNumber-RegInput" name="phoneNumber">
                        </section>
                        <section class="password-RegSection">
                            <p class="password-Reg">
                                Пароль:
                            </p>
                            <input data-passcheck="true" type="text" class="password-RegInput" id = "passReg" name="password">
                        </section>
                        <section class="passwordRepeat-RegSection">
                          <p class="passwordRepeat-Reg">
                              Повтор пароля:
                          </p>
                          <input data-repeatpasscheck="true" type="text" class="passwordRepeat-RegInput" name="passwordRepeat">
                      </section>
                        <section class="registrationButton">
                          <button type="submit" class="registrationBtn">ЗАРЕГИСТРИРОВАТЬСЯ</button>
                        </section>
                    </section>
                  </section>
                </form>
```

вот js:

```
function validation(form) {
    function contains(arr, elem) {
        let str = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (arr[i] === elem) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    function checkOnCharMoreThanOne(arr, elem) {
        let count = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (arr[i] === elem){
                count += 1;
            }
        }
        if (count > 1) return false;
        return true;
    }

    function removeError(input){
        const parent = input.parentNode;

        if (parent.classList.contains('error')){
            parent.querySelector('.error-label').remove()
            parent.classList.remove('error')
        }
    }

    function createError(input, text){
        const parent = input.parentNode;
        const errorLabel = document.createElement('label')

        errorLabel.classList.add('error-label')
        errorLabel.textContent = text

        parent.classList.add('error')

        parent.append(errorLabel)
    }

    let result = true;
    const allInputs = form.querySelectorAll('input');
    let passFlag = false;
    for (const input of allInputs){
        removeError(input)
        if (input.dataset.checkname == "true"){
            removeError(input)
            if (input.value.length > 20 || input.value.length < 2){
                createError(input, '')
                result = false
            }
            let flag = false
            for (var i = 0; i < (input.value.split("")).length; i++){
                if (input.value.split("")[i] == "1" || input.value.split("")[i] == "2" || input.value.split("")[i] == "3" || input.value.split("")[i] == "4" 
                || input.value.split("")[i] == "5" || input.value.split("")[i] == "6" || input.value.split("")[i] == "7" || input.value.split("")[i] == "8" 
                || input.value.split("")[i] == "9" || input.value.split("")[i] == "0"){
                    flag = true
                    break
                }
            }
            if (flag == true){
                createError(input, '')
                result = false
            }
        }
        if (input.dataset.repeatpasscheck == "true"){
            removeError(input)
            const pass = document.getElementById('passReg').value;
            if (input.value != pass || passFlag == false){
                createError(input, '')
                result = false
            }
        }
        if (input.dataset.passcheck == "true"){
            removeError(input)
            passFlag = true
            if (input.value.length > 20 || input.value.length < 6){
                createError(input, '')
                result = false
                passFlag = false;
            }
        }
        if (input.dataset.emailcheck == "true"){
            removeError(input)
            const parts = input.value.split('@');
            const letters = input.value.split('');
            if (contains(letters, "@") == false || contains(letters, ".") == false || checkOnCharMoreThanOne(letters, "@") == false || contains(parts[1].split('') == false) 
            || parts[0] == "" || (parts[1].split('.'))[0] == "" || (parts[1].split('.'))[1] == ""){
                createError(input, '')
                result = false
            }
        }

        if (input.dataset.length == "11"){
            removeError(input)
            if (input.value.length != 11){
                createError(input, '')
                result = false
            }
        }

        if (input.dataset.required == "true"){
            if (input.value == ""){
                createError(input, '')
    
                result = false
            }
        }

    }


    return result
}

document.getElementById('regForm').addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    
    if (validation(this) == true){
        alert("123")
    }
})
```

Comment: или нужно запускать php скрипт из скрипта js? это вообще возможно? без использования js скрипта, php запускается

Comment: А где ваш JS, который что то там делает? Может там отмена отправки формы есть? Добавьте Js скрипт в ваш вопрос

Comment: `event.preventDefault()` - отменяет штатное поведение, т.е. саму отправку формы...

Comment: спасибо большое!!! всё заработало)))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**event.preventDefault()** отменяет штатное поведение события, в вашем случае, это отправка формы.

Что бы отправлять форму, когда проверки пройдены и не отправлять в случае ошибки, поместите **event.preventDefault()** в блок `else` внутри события **submit** формы

```
document.getElementById('regForm').addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
    
    if (validation(this)){
        alert("Проверки пройдены успешно");
    } else {
        event.preventDefault();
    }

})
```